# how the strike will stay after reload the page?

Tags: javascript

when i reload   the   page , the strike   is gone . but I want to stay it after the reload the page.  how can i do that ?

```
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div>
            <span>click</span>
        </div>
        <script>
            $(function() {
                var $curParent, Content;
                $(document).delegate("span", "click", function() {
                    if ($(this).closest("s").length) {
                        Content = $(this).parent("s").html();
                        $curParent = $(this).closest("s");
                        $(Content).insertAfter($curParent);
                        $(this).closest("s").remove();
                    } else {
                        $(this).wrapAll("<s />");
                    }
                });
            });
        </script>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: `.delegate()` is deprecated, you should use `.on()`.

Comment: If you attempting to save the state of striked items you are going to need to use a cookie or browser storage so you know what to reference when the page reloads. With that you will also need to throw this code in some other handler that executes when the page reloads (i.e. doc ready), at the moment you are only calling this code when a span is clicked.

Comment: One question I have, is if you execute this logic on page load, do you actually need the on click?

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to give the best answer given the limited description, but the general idea is that you should store the state of your page in some sort of way.

Here's a simple solution that accomplishes what you want using localStorage.

```
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div>
            <span>click</span>
            <span>uoeu</span>
        </div>
        <script>
            if (localStorage.body) {
                document.body.innerHTML = localStorage.body;
            }
            $(function () {
                var $curParent, Content;
                $(document).delegate("span", "click", function () {
                    if ($(this).closest("s").length) {
                        Content = $(this).parent("s").html();
                        $curParent = $(this).closest("s");
                        $(Content).insertAfter($curParent);
                        $(this).closest("s").remove();
                    } else {
                        $(this).wrapAll("<s />");
                    }
                    localStorage.body = document.body.innerHTML;
                });
            });
        </script>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Thank you so much.

Comment: @OmarFaruk You're welcome. Please accept this as the best answer if it satisfies your needs.